# Linked Servers security context and transaction logging

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server

I have many large `logging` tables that are populating with data constantly. The information is rarely or never read and I want to move them out of the database. So, the idea is to:

1. create linked server
2. create new database on the linked server with mirror `logging` tables
3. each night/several days/week a job will delete the records from the first database and insert them into the second one

The general goal is to reduce the first database size and put it on SSD drives and put the historical not queried data on slow storage.

The `mirror` tables will have less indexes and can be additionally compressed via row,page,column store or clr compressions. It will be working under simple recovery model.

I have never used [linked servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) and have the following questions:

1. If large amount of data is deleted from the first database and inserted into the second one, only the delete operation is logged in the transaction log file of the first database, right?
2. If I have two linked servers with many databases like this:

   ```
   Server A             Server A1

   Database A           Database A1 
   Database B           Database B1
   Database C           Database C1
   ```

   How can a restrict a user who has can query database `A` and `A1`, to query database `B1` and `C1`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a linked server for this. It will likely be slow. Linked servers are suitable for small queries over remote databases, not for bulk loading data.

I would use SSIS or whichever ETL system you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will check the `SSIS` solution either.

Answer (score 0):

Ad1. For me question is bit unclear. Transaction log is not "audit log" for db, for short - it keeps history of transactions. Inserts will be on one server, deletes on another.

Ad2. Sure you can restricts rights. Server connects to linked server with security context (user/pass etc) which is given in link properites. Set needed permissions for remote server user.
Nice tutorial is [on databasejournal](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3103331_2/Linked-Servers-on-MS-SQL-Part-2.htm)